# How to fetch data from more than one tables in single scan?

Tags: hbase

I am developing a small social network application and facing N+1 select problem.

I have two tables, Post and Comment that contribute the major role in application.

I am storing all the posts in Post table and comments on the posts are stored in Comment table. I am fetching the data using partial key scan feature in the following manner.

```
 Post: Start row = userID  | Stop Row = userID +1

 Comment: Start row = postID | Stop Row = postID +1
```

And here is the code snippet, which is used to fetch the data

```
 HTable table = resource.getTable(getTableName());

 Scan scan = new Scan();
 scan.setStartRow(Bytes.toBytes(prefixId.toString()));
 scan.setStopRow(Bytes.toBytes(prefixId.toString() + 1));

 ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan); //TODO store the scanner in cache.
 Result[] results = scanner.next(pageSize);
```

Problem with code is that I can fetch the all post for a user in single query. But for each post I have to make separate query to fetch all comments.  I analyzed the HBase client Scan API, but not able to find the solution to make it possible in a single query or at most two queries; one for posts and other for comments.

I came to know about filters, but filters are again performance bottleneck.

I have just started with NOSQL technology and very new to HBase. Please help me at design/framework level to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get required data in a single scan,
  1. By keeping all comments into the same table(POST), create runtime column as name comment-(timestamp) or comment-(number) whenever a new comment comes.

2.In other way you can create two column Family one is 'Post' & another is 'Comment', as comments can be more, so set number of versions to largest(Optimal) value for Column family 'Comment'.

Comment: I could go with your first solution, if comment table could have only one column. But, my comment table is complex one and contains more than one qualifiers. I couldn't get you on second solution. Are you talking about maintaining one to many relationship in a single table i.e. a flat-wide design?

Comment: even if you like to keep two separate table than,   you can use get command to fetch all comments by passing List of keys, if you don't want to use RowKeyFilter

Comment: Yes, as one post can have many comments so, its better to keep in separate column-family when it has 1:N relationship

Comment: Thanks for your input Sandeep. I am planning to keep all the comment keys in Post table and will use the get API to fetch all comments by row key.